# How to tag or mention a person in Gmail with just the first name?

Tags: gmail

I have noticed a colleague manages to send emails (our company uses Google Workspace, and so Gmail) and is able to **tag/mention just a first name that leads to a link** `mailto:<email address>`.
I tried to do so with both the `@` or `+` followed by typing a name and choosing the correct person, but then the full name is shown, and then when I try to remove the last name, the whole link is gone.

Comment: Same question but for Google Chat [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172094/121083). Quick answer for Google Chat: Not possible as of Sept '23

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer.

1. type your mention as per normal, `@<few characters and select the correct one>`
2. move the text cursor (the blinking `|`) to beside the mention.
3. wait for the tooltip to appear, and choose 'Change'.
4. click change and modify the desired display name accordingly.

If there is a better way to achieve this please post another answer