# Is it possible to tag or mention a person in Google Chat with just their first name?

Tags: google-chat

In Google Chat, I would like to tag/mention a colleague using just their first name, not their entire name. Is this possible?

(This question is basically identical to [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/165309/121083), but for Google Chat rather than Gmail)

Comment: **No.** My understanding as of Sept. 2023 is that this is not possible.